# How do I update an app widget from another activity?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a homescreen widget that I want to update when a preference is changed from PreferenceActivity, inside `onPreferenceChanged`. How do I call any of the methods in  my widget provider class inside the preference activity?

UPDATED DETAILS:
Essentially, I want to call `onRecieve` from another activity, and I was looking for the implementation for this.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Activity, send an Intent using sendBroadcast(). In your AppWidgetProvider implement handling the Intent there by implementing the onReceive() method.
Be aware, that AppWidgetProvider is an extended BroadcastReceiver.

For more information, see the official documentation here.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/#AppWidgetProvider

Comment: Thanks for the response. This made it click for me, I was able to use an `onPreferenceChangedListener` in the `onCreate` of my PreferenceActivity to send a broadcast to `onRecieve` any time a preference was changed. From there, I was able to restart the widget instance to change the layout resource of the widget.